# Contrapositive of an Implication

Tags: logic

Why is the contrapostive of an implication equivalent to its normal truth table? i.e. why is this the case:

$$
\begin{array}{c|l|c}
p & q & \text~p \implies \text~q  \\
\hline
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
$$

Given that the nomal implication table is:

$$
\begin{array}{c|l|c}
B & A & B \implies A  \\
\hline
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
$$

Specifically, in the first table and first row: 
        p = 1, thus ~p = 0; q = 0, thus ~q = 1. Given these, if one enters these values ( B=0 and A=1) into the second, basic implication table, then the statement is true.

An example would help. I cannot grasp the meaning so I can't really think of any good examples.

Comment: you sure about your resource ?

Answer (score 3):

Your first truth table isn't correct: the first and second rows have the wrong truth value. For it to be true, the heading should be $\sim q \implies \sim p$.

Comment: Ah, Ha! A fool I am. So the counterpositive not only switches the truth of the values, but also flips them. Hence counter-positive.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Think about the following two statements:

> If you are a cat, then you are an animal.

and

> If you are not an animal, you are not a cat.

These statements are contrapositives of each other, but they express the same fact: namely that *being an animal* is a necessary condition of *being a cat*.  Another compatible way of thinking about it is that "cats" are a subset of "animals".